# How can I change the value of a field in node / [id] / edit?

Tags: views, nodes, hooks

I should change the value of a field before it is rendered. I tried with [NAME_MODULE]_node_view but it is not invoked when I edit the node.

Thank you so much.

Comment: That's a form so you'd want to alter the form and to do that you'd use https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x The hook_node_view is only for viewing the node rather than editing

Comment: and you'll need to target the `['#default_value']` key

Answer (score 0):

I alter my forms with the following:

```
function mymodule_form_test_edit_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // code here...
}
```